# Adding sequence numbering column to Qweb reports

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb

I need to add a sequence numbering column to order lines table in QWeb reports like [SO, Quotations, POs, delivery Slip &, etc..].

```
  <table class="table table-condensed mt48" t-if="not o.move_line_ids">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                            <th><strong>Ordered Quantity</strong></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td  t-foreach="not o.move_line_ids" t-as="i">
                               <t t-set="i" t-value="1" />
                                <span t-esc="i"/> 
                               <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/> 
                          </td>
                            <td><span t-field="move.product_id"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <span t-field="move.ordered_qty"/>
                                <span t-field="move.product_uom"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Sadly, I couldn't make it work. It gives me an empty error.

Comment: Do `o.move_line_ids` (on line 1) and `o.move_lines` (on line 8) refer to the same field? If so, that's one problem. Then you want to show the table when there are move lines so, `t-if="not o.move_line_ids"` should be `t-if="o.move_line_ids"`

Comment: @AdanCortes thanks for the reply. I have edited the code, I messed up. Can you check a let me know what goes wrong? appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<t t-set="i" t-value="1" />
<table class="table table-condensed mt48" t-if="o.move_line_ids">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>#</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Ordered Quantity</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td t-foreach="o.move_line_ids" t-as="move">
        <span t-esc="i"/> 
        <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/> 
      </td>
      <td><span t-field="move.product_id.name"/></td>
      <td>
        <span t-field="move.ordered_qty"/>
        <span t-field="move.product_uom"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```